# Why onClick of removing a child element needs to be clicked twice?

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to remove the first-child in an list, and this action is an onclick event of button, the onclick method is: `list.removeChild(list.firstItem)`. However, I have to click the button twice to see the effect, **WHY**?

I found en [example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_node_removechild4) for removing first item in list by calling `item.parentNode.removeChild(item)`. 
The problem is that when I change the handler method to `list.removeChild(list.firstChild)`, I need to click twice to see the effect.

I've tried `list.removeChild(list.firstChildElement)` and it works as expected (first item disappear by one click), **WHY** this method don't need double-click compared to `list.removeChild(list.firstChild)` method.

Example:

- HTML:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li id="first">Coffee</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="removeLi()">Remove li</button>
```

- One click to see the effect:

```
// 1:
let item = document.getElementById("first");
function removeLi() {
  item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
}
```

```
// 2:
const list = document.getElementById("list");
function removeLi() {
  list.removeChild(list.firstChildElement);
}
```

- Double click needed:

```
const list = document.getElementById("list");
function removeLi() {
  list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
}
```

Comment: `firstChild` selects the first node, which may not be an Element - it may be a text node

Comment: The reason of removal happening after multiple clicks is that `firstChild` may have different nodes type, so that DOM API can not fetch that HTML element the first time. Is that right ?                                                                     @CertainPerformance

Comment: The first time, it's a text node - the second time, it's your `<li>` element